# Using mnemonic triangles for composition of hyperbolic trigonometric functions and their inverses

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

The composition of circular trigonometric functions, like $\cos(\tan^{-1}(x))$, can be derived drawing a right angle triangle and applying Pythagoras' theorem and the definition of sine and cosine in terms of the sides of the triangle. This is shown for example in this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions

I tried to find an analog for hyperbolic trig functions, but I haven't found anything. Does there exist a similar mnemonic for them?

Comment: I don't really have an answer (this isn't something that has ever really been necessary for me to think about in the past), but remember that hyperbolic trigonometric functions can be defined in terms of the unit hyperbola in much the same way that the "usual" trigonometric functions are defined in terms of the unit circle.  A given angle $\theta/2$ will intersect the hyperbola at a point which has coordinates $(\cosh(\theta),\sinh(\theta))$.  The slope of that angle is $\tanh(\theta)$.  Drawing that picture *might* lead to a useful mnemonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperbolic equivalent to the trigonometric mnemonic $SOHCAHTOA$ is $$CHASOATOH$$

If you are familiar with $SOHCAHTOA$ then the hyperbolic one should be self-explanatory.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome